# HKSourceQuery not returning values when using with predicateForWorkouts

Tags: swift, swiftui, healthkit, applehealth

I am trying to load all sources for cycling workouts. For this, I am using a `HKSourceQuery` like in the following code block:

```
let workoutPredicate = HKQuery.predicateForWorkouts(with: .cycling)
let query = HKSourceQuery(sampleType: .workoutType(), samplePredicate: workoutPredicate) { (query, samples, error) in
    // print(samples, error) prints nil, nil
}
```

However, unexpectedly, bot `error` and `samples` are `nil`. There exist cycling workouts in the health store, both from my own app and from an Apple Watch. Passing `samplePredicate: nil` returns sources. Passing `samplePredicate: sourcePredicate` with `let sourcePredicate = HKQuery.predicateForObjects(from: .default())` works. Only querying for all cycling workouts does not work.

**How do I load all sources for cycling workouts from HealthKit?**